# Escape "<br>" in xsl file

Tags: xslt, escaping

How do I escape the `<`, `>` characters in XSL?

The relevant code line is:

```
<td class="some_class" onclick='pop(this.title)'>
```

Which I'd like to change to:

```
<td class="some_class" onclick='pop(this.title+"<br>"+this.name')>
```

Which fails with the following message (in Chrome):

```
error on line 928 at column 60: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;`:

```
<td class="some_class" onclick='pop(this.title+"&lt;br&gt;"+this.name')>
```

Comment: Wow! That was very helpful! Sorry I can't +1

Comment: Why can't you do that? I spend lots of effort helping you out.

Comment: I think they ban users with dissociative identity disorder from voting up.

Comment: We don't think that's fair.